# What happened to the webcomic "Scraps" by onthebridgebetween

Tags: post-apocalyptic, webcomics

So I was looking for another webcomic on Tapas that I had bookmarked and stumbled on "scraps". I clicked on it, thinking it was the webcomic I was looking for (by the way I already found the first comic don't worry about this) and now it's gone. I remember it being about a post-apocalypse world about two guys scavenging stuff, so what happened to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not immediately clear why artist BackyardGrave (AKA ōwen, AKA ✂️) abandoned Tapas shortly after completing *Scraps* in 2019, but it's worthy of note that they then posted it onto a variety of other sites including [Itch.io](https://backyardgrave.itch.io/scraps) which allow direct monetisation. Presumably, having enjoyed some modest success with it, they decided that they wanted to get money for it rather than just giving it away for free.

In more recent years they've developed a considerable body of work on [Pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/34145986/artworks?p=4), a largely Japanese-focused art sharing site. This seems a more natural home to them since they appear to be living and working in Japan and now producing their art primarily for their own amusement rather than attempting to do so professionally.